# Looping over 2 columns of data and then returning data in column 3 if column 1 and 2 are a certain value

Tags: r, loops

I am a newbie in R but I have come across an issue that requires some help.

Assume that there are 2 columns in my data CSV file. (Let's call it X)

I also have another file of data of which I use to check against the CSV file (Let's call it Y).

X has 3 columns of data with headers: a,b,c.

Y has 3 columns of data with the same headers: a,b,c

I want R to check columns a and b in X with a and b in Y.

If a and b in X match a and b in Y respectively, column c in Y is used to replace column c in X.

It doesn't matter what column c in X is.

How should I formulate this code?

X <- as.vector(a,b,c)
Y <- as.vector(a,b,c)

for x in ...

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please give a reproducible example .

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

use a join construction:
I prefer to work with dplyr, but `merge` in base is also a possibility.

```
set.seed(314)

x <- data.frame(a = sample(1:10,10),
                b = sample(1:10,10),
                c = sample(1:10,10))

y <- data.frame(a = sample(1:10,10),
                b = sample(1:10,10),
                c = sample(1:10,10))

library(dplyr)

x %>% left_join(y, by=c('a','b')) %>% mutate(c = ifelse(!is.na(c.y),c.y,c.x))
```

results in (I kept the c.x and c.y column for illustration):

```
    a  b c.x c.y  c
1   1  4   7  NA  7
2   3  2   5  NA  5
3   7  9   9  NA  9
4   2  8   2  NA  2
5   8 10   1  NA  1
6   6  7   3  NA  3
7  10  3  10  NA 10
8   5  5   6  NA  6
9   9  1   8   4  4
10  4  6   4  NA  4
```